# How to handle if the user interrupts the page load?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

In my extension, I am relying on DOMContentLoaded event. This works fine. But fails if the user cancels the page load in middle. And my extension simply doesn't work. I want it to degrade gracefully here. So, is there anyway for handling this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use an [nsIWebProgressListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebProgressListener) to monitor the progress of page load events. The `onStateChange` method executes with a status of `STATE_STOP` when the request has finished, even if the user interrupted the page load.

Here's a simple example:

```
const STATE_START = Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_START;  
const STATE_STOP = Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP;  

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    gBrowser.addProgressListener({
        QueryInterface: function(aIID) {  
            if (aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsIWebProgressListener) ||  
                aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsWeakReference) ||  
                aIID.equals(Components.interfaces.nsISupports))  
                return this;  
            throw Components.results.NS_NOINTERFACE;  
        },  

        onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aFlag, aStatus) {  
            if (aFlag & STATE_STOP) {  
                // load finished or was stopped
                alert("stop");
            }  
        },  

        onLocationChange: function(aProgress, aRequest, aURI) { },  
        onProgressChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, curSelf, maxSelf, curTot, maxTot) { },  
        onStatusChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStatus, aMessage) { },  
        onSecurityChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aState) { }  
    });
}, false);
```

This is a toy example, of course. Further reading on some implementation details:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads#WebProgressListeners